# Messanger bot for magento

Tags: magento2, messages, facebook

For my online store, I want to install Facebook messenger bot.

What is the best solution for this? And extension should be free.

Comment: This [extension](https://www.mageworx.com/magento-facebook-messenger.html) is free till march 31